# Checking Values Stored In A Column In A Date of Birth Format in Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently trying to get all records in a database that have a date of birth set to a future date.  But I am not sure how to check the existing values stored and make sure they are greater than/less than today's date.

Currently all I have is,

```
select * from [table_name]
where [column_name] =  .........;
```

the formats of the saved dates are DD-FEB-YY and they are stored in a column within a person table.

Comment: With a YY format, you cannot distinguish future years from past years.

Comment: What's the datatype of this column? If it's a `DATE` you don't have to care about format, simply use `where col >= current_date` to find future dates. If it's a string with that format you're in trouble.

Comment: "the formats of the saved dates are DD-FEB-YY" Fix that. Then get back to us.

Comment: You need to include the data type for the column.  If it's a character string, you're hosed unless you make some assumptions about what YY values are valid (and those assumptions will break down for old enough people — if there are any centenarians in the database, you're completely hosed, and you can easily run into problems with people in their 70s-90s too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `CURDATE()` function to get today's date.  This will return all records later than today:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dateColumn > CURDATE()
```